# Any not maximized window in focus disappears when I hold Ctrl+Alt

Tags: 16.04, shortcut-keys, window

The menu is displayed, but the application isn't visible after holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> (and any shortcut-keys with)

[image]

I can focus on it and I can view menu, but can't view self window when use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>. But window appears when I click it on Launcher.

System:
Just installed Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit, video Intel HD 3000.

Comment: Just installed Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit, video Intel HD 3000.

Comment: Instead of a comment, please edit that info into your question.